# Buscar registro en mysql que no contenga un dato

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta en la cual quiero buscar dentro de una tabla un registro pero no quiero que contenga un dato especifico, es decir, evitar los registros que contengan cierta palabra.

Ejemplo:

```
db
Reporte fecha        hora    Tecnico
12      24/03/2020   04:35   Rodrigo Martinez
13      24/03/2020   06:20   Rodrigo Gonzales
14      24/03/2020   06:35   Rodrigo Perez

Select * from reportes where Tecnico like '%%Rodrigo%%';
```

Lo que daría como resultado:

```
Reporte fecha        hora    Tecnico
12      24/03/2020   04:35   Rodrigo Martinez
13      24/03/2020   06:20   Rodrigo Gonzales
14      24/03/2020   06:35   Rodrigo Perez
```

¿Como hago que busque todos esos registros pero que no contengan 06:35, por ejemplo?

```
(Que devuelva algo como: 12      24/03/2020   04:35   Rodrigo Martinez
13      24/03/2020   06:20   Rodrigo Gonzales)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues debería alcanzar con un operador que indique la exclusión de dicho valor; es decir que se viera mas o menos así:

```
Select * from reportes 
where Tecnico like '%%Rodrigo%%'
AND hora <> "06:35";
```

Es decir:

- Necesitas que aparte de la condición del `WHERE` exista una segunda condición obligatoria
- Para unir ambas condiciones necesitamos el operador `AND`
- Usamos el símbolo `<>` para indicar que hora sea diferente de algún valor

Dado lo anterior le decimos:

> Selecciona todo de la tabla reportes donde el técnico sea igual a Rodrigo y la fecha no sea 06:35.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from reportes where hora <> '06:35';
Select * from reportes where hora != '06:35';
```

Cualquier de las dos ejecutan diferencia